# How to Execute a Transformation for Multiple elements with the Same Function

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, rotation, transformation

I have 2 elements which should both rotateY(180deg) every time my button is clicked, however the code I have now only rotates the first one. How do I achieve a transfomation for all my elements? (Vanilla JS)

```
.question {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                transition:transform 0.5s;
                transform-style:preserve-3d;
                
            }
  .sceneQ {
                width:600px;
                height:150px;
            }
            .questionTransform {
                transform:rotateY(190deg)
            }
 .face {
                
                text-align:center;
                backface-visibility:hidden;
            }
            .back {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }
```

```
<button id="hintbtn" onclick="doTransform()">Do Transform</button>

<div id="sceneQ1" class="sceneQ">
        <div class="question" id="Q1">
            <div class="face front">
            <p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
         </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <p>Someplace in America...</p>
            </div>
        </div> </div>

<div id="sceneQ2" class="sceneQ">
        <div class="question" id="Q2">
            <div class="face front">
            <p>In what decade were the first kind of skateboards created?</p>
                </div>
        <div class="face back">
            <p>After the 2nd World War...</p>
            </div>
        </div> </div>
```

```
function doTransform() {
                const element = document.querySelector('.sceneQ .question')
                element.classList.toggle('questionTransform')
            }
```

Comment: Use querySelectorAll instead of querySelector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you. Check [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/loop-queryselectorall-matches/) for more info

```js
function doTransform() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sceneQ .question');

[].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
  element.classList.toggle('questionTransform')

});
            }
```

```css
.question {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                transition:transform 0.5s;
                transform-style:preserve-3d;
                
            }
  .sceneQ {
                width:600px;
                height:150px;
            }
            .questionTransform {
                transform:rotateY(190deg)
            }
 .face {
                
                text-align:center;
                backface-visibility:hidden;
            }
            .back {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
            }
```

```html
<button id="hintbtn" onclick="doTransform()">Do Transform</button>

<div id="sceneQ1" class="sceneQ">
        <div class="question" id="Q1">
            <div class="face front">
            <p>Where does skateboarding originate from?</p>
         </div>
            <div class="face back">
                <p>Someplace in America...</p>
            </div>
        </div> </div>

<div id="sceneQ2" class="sceneQ">
        <div class="question" id="Q2">
            <div class="face front">
            <p>In what decade were the first kind of skateboards created?</p>
                </div>
        <div class="face back">
            <p>After the 2nd World War...</p>
            </div>
        </div> </div>
```